# Cloudfront behavior not redirecting traffic to ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

I have a problem with a Cloudfront distribution.

This distribution has 3 origins:

1. An S3 Bucket containing a static website
2. An ELB containing CMS and API
3. A custom Lambda function (not part of the problem I think)

I have 2 behaviors:

1. `/cms/*` routing all traffic via HTTPS to my ELB.
2. `*` Default behavior routing request to my S3 Bucket.

However when accessing any URL like `https://host.com/cms/assets/img.jpg` I get to see the 404 page that is contained in my S3 bucket. I'm currently forwarding headers to my ELB via AllViewer policy. Also when I put the ELB as origin of the default behavior everything works perfectly.

It seems that Cloudfront just doesn't follow the path pattern defined in my behavior.

[image]

Some more facts:

- Traffic from CF to my ELB is HTTPS-only
- Cloudfront is using TLS-certificate from ACM for my domain.
- ELB also has TLS-certificate for domain from ACM
- I don't think it's an HTTPS related error, as ELB as origin works when used through default behavior

Comment: I'd recommend looking into Cloudfront functions. Often times you just need a bit more control. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-functions.html